# Images not showing up on Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari, compatibility

I've created this mosaic of images for my new website. I might have made it mode complicated that it needs to be but that was the only way I could think of to make that effect. When you hover on an image, the name appear on a semi-transparent color and when you click a lightbox appears.

```
<div class="actress-photos-div">
    <div class="actress-photo1">
           <div class="1-wrap actress-photo"><a href="#1-popup" class="open-popup-link"><div class="1-mask mask"><div>Actress 1</div></div></a><div class="photo"><img src="IMG/1.jpg"/></div></div>
           <div class="2-wrap actress-photo"><a href="#2-popup" class="open-popup-link"><div class="2-mask mask"><div>Actress 2</div></div></a><div class="photo"><img src="IMG/2.jpg"/></div></div>
           <div class="3-wrap actress-photo"><a href="#3-popup" class="open-popup-link"><div class="3-mask mask"><div>Actress 3</div></div></a><div class="photo"><img src="IMG/3.jpg"/></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works great on Chrome and Firefox but the images don't show up at all on Safari. The masks appear but at their minimum size. The links work.

Here is the CSS, I figured that if I remove the class "photo" it works, but I lose all my formatting..

```
.actress-photos-div{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:85vw;
    margin-top:20px;
    height:38vw;
    }

 .actress-photo1{
    position:inherit;
    float:left;
    width:38%;
    height:100%;
    left:0%;
    }

.mask{
    background-color:rgba(227,210,23,0.84);
    z-index:20;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    }

.mask div{
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
    height:20px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    }

.photo{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width: intrinsic;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    }

.photo img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }   

.alfre-wrap{
    width:98%;
    height:60%;
    }

.alfre-wrap:hover .alfre-mask{
    visibility:visible;
    }
```

Is there a way to make it compatible with Safari?

Comment: You're probably making the DIVs that contain the photos smaller than the photos themselves.

Comment: Odd restart Safari and see if the issue persist

Comment: float:left; seems to be the issue but I can't figure out how to fix that. Restarted it but it didn't help.